# How I take the shipping method output in totals frame in Magento

Tags: magento, methods, checkout

The Magento checkout has a line that show the totals in the file:

frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('totals'); ?>
```

But this line shows also the shipping method if customer choose a freight method and I didn't find this to take it of my total page, I know that I can't delete it from the database because this information is used in the freight choice.

Answer (score 3):

For removing this data from the total you need to override the following classes:

To hide it in shopping cart page:

**Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Shipping::fetch()** method needs to be overridden via custom module:

```
public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
{
    $originalShippingDescription = $address->getShippingDescription(); // Keep old description value
    $address->unsShippingDescription(); // Removes description of shipping method
    parent::fetch($address);
    $address->setShippingDescription($originalShippingDescription); // Sets back original description of shipping method
    return $this;
}
```

To hide it on order overview pages in the user account, you need to perform another customization of **Mage_Sales_Block_Order_Totals** class. For this purpose you need to create a new block extended from **Mage_Core_Block_Abstract**

1. Create block in some your custom module

   ```
   <?php 
   class Custom_Module_Block_Shipping_Total extents Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
   {
       public function initTotals()
       {
           if ($this->getParentBlock() && $this->getParentBlock()->getTotal('shipping')) {
              $this->getParentBlock()->getTotal('shipping')->setLabel($this->__('Shipping & Handling'));
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add layout updates to include you block into order view.

   ```
    <layout>
    <!-- Your custom total on invoices view -->
       <custom_invoice_totals>
           <reference name="invoice_totals">
               <block name="custom_total" type="custom_module/shipping_total" />
           </reference>
       </custom_invoice_totals>

       <!-- Your custom total on shipments view -->
       <custom_shipment_totals>
           <reference name="shipment_totals">
               <block name="custom_total" type="custom_module/shipping_total" />
           </reference>
       </custom_shipment_totals>

       <!-- Your custom total on creditmemos view -->
       <custom_creditmemo_totals>
           <reference name="creditmemo_items">
               <block name="custom_total" type="custom_module/shipping_total" />
           </reference>
       </custom_creditmemo_totals>


       <!-- Applying your handles to particular pages in customer account -->
       <sales_order_view>
           <update handle="custom_order_totals" />
       </sales_order_view>

       <sales_order_print>
           <update handle="custom_order_totals" />
       </sales_order_print>

       <sales_email_order_items>
           <update handle="custom_order_totals" />
       </sales_email_order_items>

       <!-- applies your total in email -->
       <sales_email_order_items>
           <update handle="custom_order_totals" />
       </sales_email_order_items>

       <sales_guest_view>
           <update handle="custom_order_totals" />
       </sales_guest_view>

       <!-- invoice pages -->
       <sales_order_invoice>
           <update handle="custom_invoice_totals" />
       </sales_order_invoice>

       <sales_order_printinvoice>
           <update handle="custom_invoice_totals" />
       </sales_order_printinvoice>

       <sales_email_order_invoice_items>
           <update handle="custom_invoice_totals" />
       </sales_email_order_invoice_items>

       <sales_guest_invoice>
           <update handle="custom_invoice_totals" />
       </sales_guest_invoice>

       <!-- shipment pages -->
       <sales_order_shipment>
           <update handle="custom_shipment_totals" />
       </sales_order_shipment>

       <sales_order_printshipment>
           <update handle="custom_shipment_totals" />
       </sales_order_printshipment>

       <sales_email_order_shipment_items>
           <update handle="custom_shipment_totals" />
       </sales_email_order_shipment_items>

       <sales_guest_shipment>
           <update handle="custom_shipment_totals" />
       </sales_guest_shipment>

       <!-- creditmemo pages -->
       <sales_order_creditmemo>
           <update handle="custom_creditmemo_totals" />
       </sales_order_creditmemo>

       <sales_order_printcreditmemo>
           <update handle="custom_creditmemo_totals" />
       </sales_order_printcreditmemo>

       <sales_email_order_creditmemo_items>
           <update handle="custom_creditmemo_totals" />
       </sales_email_order_creditmemo_items>

       <sales_guest_creditmemo>
           <update handle="custom_creditmemo_totals" />
       </sales_guest_creditmemo>
    </layout>
   ```

After such customization on all pages on the frontend your shipping total will be without information about shipping method...

Answer (score 0):

in your local cart.phtml, use following snippet:

```
<div class="cart-totals-wrapper">
    <div class="cart-totals">
        <div class="cart-totals-container">
            <!-- <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('totals'); ?> -->
            <?php 
                $_quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
                $_cartValue = 0;
                $_items = $_quote->getAllItems();
                foreach ($_items as $_item) {
                    $_cartValue += $_item->getRowTotalInclTax();
                }
            ?>
            <table id="shopping-cart-totals-table">
                <colgroup>
                    <col>
                    <col width="1">
                </colgroup>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="a-right" colspan="1" style=""><?php echo $this->__('Subtotal'); ?></td>
                    <td class="a-right" style="">
                        <span class="price"><?php echo $_quote->getStore()->formatPrice($_cartValue); ?></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <p class="message"><?php echo $this->__('Shipping will be calculated at checkout'); ?></p>
        </div>
```